# How do I prove that a set $A$ can have at most one least upper bound?

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-writing

So of course if $A$ is null then there are no least upper bounds. And so then if we take $A=[x:x^2<10]$ then we have $A$ has 1 least upper bound: namely $\sqrt{10}$. So then I'm thinking assume we have a non empty set $A$ which has more than one least upper bound and finding a contradiction.

Comment: While I haven't tried this myself, my gut instinct would be to treat this like you would treat a lot of "uniqueness" proofs (i.e. that the least upper bound, if it exists, is unique). So if a set has a least upper bound $\alpha$, suppose it also has another least upper bound $\beta$, and try to show $\alpha = \beta$.

Comment: I've tried fiddling around with this but can't seem to get anywhere

Comment: Hint: if you have two suprema, they must be less than or equal to each other from definition. Do you see why?

Comment: yes I see why. I've written an answer below.

Answer (score 3):

If you have two least upper bounds $u_1$ and $u_2$ then we have $u_1\le u_2$ and $u_2 \le u_1$

Thus they are the same.

Answer (score 0):

By the definition of supremum: if we have 1 supremum $\alpha$ and the other $\beta$ then

$$\alpha\leq\beta$$ and $$\beta\leq\alpha$$
For these to both hold, $$\alpha=\beta$$
Thus we have at most 1 supremum for any set $A$